# MySQL INSERT query does not update the DB

Tags: php, mysql

attent table :

id int(11) primary key

userID int (11) forigen key from users table

date date

start_time text

end_time text

approv enum default 0

my query :

```
             $sql = "INSERT INTO attent ".
                   "(id,userID,date,start_time,end_time,approv) ".
               "VALUES ".
               "('NULL','$userid','$date','$start_time','$end_time','NULL')";

              $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
```

I got config.php file that help communicate with dB. I did a few insert queries before and all of them work just fine. I can not understand where is my mistake.

Comment: Cannot add NULL string to id int(11), Also cannot add string NULL in tinyint

Comment: remove the quotes around your NULL values

Comment: PHP will usually tell you what's wrong if you just let it: [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: If your ID column is an auto_increment.. you do not need to pass it at all

Comment: why are you concat string here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your query as below:-

```
"INSERT INTO attent(`id`,`userID`,`date`,`start_time`,`end_time`,`approv`)
VALUES(NULL,'$userid','$date','$start_time','$end_time',NULL)"
```

Comment: You can't add null string to int attribute.

Comment: @Saty:  my mistake date is a keyword but not reserved.

Comment: @abhishekGurjar: Yes you can. try it. If id is PK then it is not possible but if not then it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this use back tick,because date is reserved word in mysql

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `attent` ".
               "(`id`,`userID`,`date`,`start_time`,`end_time`,`approv`) ".
           "VALUES ".
           "('','$userid','$date','$start_time','$end_time','')";
```

Comment: Date is keyword in mysql but not reserved . Check there is no __(R)__ after date https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: delete id and did as above and still does not work :(

Comment: @surfer, try with blank `''` instead of NULL

Comment: @Saty , thanks for comment, now I saw, but yes back tick is also good practice.

Comment: ok guys so I  just did a restart to my local server and query updated. also I got no problem to insert null to id field even if he auto  increment . someone can explain what is the proper way?   want to say thanks to all of you for you help and comments :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to understand what's going on if you will try to put such a query manually through e.g. phpMyAdmin

I don't know your table structure but try to skip `id` attribute as it's often autoincrementable. You can always skip the fields that is not set to `NOT NULL`.

Like that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `attent` ".
       "(`userID`,`date`,`start_time`,`end_time`,`approv`) ".
       "VALUES ".
       "('$userid','$date','$start_time','$end_time','')";
```